# boto3 NoCredentialsError from AWS provided code

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I've used Azure (which has been a pleasure to use) but need to use AWS for work.

I'm attempting to send a local file to an s3 container and the code provided by AWS in documentation doesn't seem to be working. Why is it not working and how can one fix it? Here is the Python code that's based on. I did remove the logging due an error when installing that library with pip.

[https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html][1]

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import os


def upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name=None):
    """Upload a file to an S3 bucket

    :param file_name: File to upload
    :param bucket: Bucket to upload to
    :param object_name: S3 object name. If not specified then file_name is used
    :return: True if file was uploaded, else False
    """

    # If S3 object_name was not specified, use file_name
    if object_name is None:
        object_name = os.path.basename(file_name)

    # Upload the file
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
    except ClientError as e:
        return False
    return True

upload_file("test.csv", "call-lists")


  [1]: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html
```

Error I am receiving:
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

I don't see where I am supposed to place credentials nor am I sure what credentials need to be provided.

Comment: "doesn't seem to be working" - is not specific. What **exactly** is happening. Any errors, timeouts, ... ??

Comment: Realized I left that out. Added.

Comment: So how exactly are you specifying aws credentials for your code to use?

Comment: I don't see anything in the code AWS provided in the linked documentation to include credentials. I'm also not sure which credentials those would be. I'm not able to locate any reference to passing credentials in the AWS documentation which is what brings me to Stackoverflow.

Comment: So the code that you are using, runs on EC2 instance, lambda, ecs?

Comment: I've been running it locally before trying to run it on Lambda. That's not possible I'm assuming by your response. But how would a Lambda function be able to access a local file?

Comment: AWS has something analogous to DefaultAzureCredential. All AWS SDKs provide a default [credential provider chain](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html#configuring-credentials). On your local dev machine you'd typically configure a config profile for an IAM user, and while running on any compute service in AWS, you'd use an IAM role. Also,  note that an "S3 container" is an S3 bucket.

Comment: And yes, you can run this code locally. It doesn't have to be run on AWS. You simply need to provide credentials locally (typically an IAM user access key and secret key, configured in ~/.aws/credentials).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code runs on an Amazon EC2 instance or an AWS Lambda function, then you should **assign an IAM Role** to the instance/function. This will provide credentials that the code can access.

If you are running the code on your own computer (not an EC2 instance / Lambda function), then you will need to store credentials in a configuration file. The easiest way to do this is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws configure` command.

It will request an **Access Key** and a **Secret Key**. You can obtain these from the **Security credentials** tab on an IAM User in the IAM management console (*not* IAM Identity Center).

Answer (score 1):

If you run the code locally, you have to correctly setup AWS credentails on your computer. How to do it, is explained in details in AWS docs:

- [Configuration and credential file settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html)